# Office JavaScript API: set alt text of Word.Table

Tags: office-js

When I created a Word table with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` I could set the alternative text by setting the values of the `Title` and/or `Descr` properties.

```vb
var tbl = document.Tables.Add(range, 2, 2);
tbl.Title = "This is the title";
tbl.Descr = "This is the description";
```

This would result in table properties like this:

[image]

When I create a table using the Office JavaScript API there is no `title` or `descr` property.

```js
const tbl = range.insertTable(2, 2, "After");
tbl.title <-- is missing
tbl.descr <-- is missing
```

How can I do this via the Office JavaScript Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Word JavaScript API documentation for the [Table Object](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/table?product=word?product=word), accessing the `title` and `descr` properties of a table in Word is not currently supported in Office.js.

Comment: Could you post the link where this is mentioned? I couldn't find anything regarding descr and title in the documentation of the Table Object.

Comment: At any given point in time, the docs should be the source of truth regarding which properties and methods are supported on an object. The fact that the title and desc properties are *not* mentioned (documented) within the Table Object page that I linked to indicates that they are not currently supported.